Why does the magnetic field penetrate inside the superconductor?
why does the magnetic field penetrate (that is exponentially decaying over the thin region) inside the superconductor? Does it actually contradicts Meissner effect?

I suspect this question will be closed for "needing details." You could mean how flux vortices go through type 2 superconductors, or you could mean that there is a thin region over which magnetic fields exponentially decay even when the Meissner effect is working. You should describe more clearly what you've heard so that people know what they should explain.

I edited the question. Can you please comment on it?

You are looking for an explanation or derivation of the London penetration depth $\lambda_L=\sqrt{\frac{m}{\mu_0 n q^2}}$ ?

I think this is simply because of the impurities in the structure of the superconductor. I have read before that extra-purified superconductors actually perform worse in some situations, like how stable it floats in a magnetic field. Some impurities allow leakages of magnetic flux that makes it overall less sensitive to the changes in the magnetic field.
What I wanna say is, in real-life situations it is mostly because of impurities. As far as I know there isn't a complete study that contradicts the Meissner Effect.
Sorry for bad English. It's not my first language.
Edit:
-I humbly apologies because I have only now realized what you were actually asking about. My previous answer was about leakages that can completely go through the superconducting material even below the critical temperature. But you were asking about the concept of penetration depth if I understand right.
In Type II superconductors, the magnetic field can penetrate the material to a certain extent, albeit not entirely. This penetration occurs within a thin layer near the surface of the superconductor and is characterized by an exponential decay of the magnetic field intensity with increasing depth. This depth is known as the penetration depth, and it depends on factors like the material properties and temperature.
The partial penetration of magnetic fields in Type II superconductors is related to the formation of vortices within the material. When the external magnetic field surpasses a critical value, vortices, or small regions with circulating supercurrents, start to form. These vortices can allow the magnetic field to penetrate the superconductor to some extent.
I suggest reading more about the topic online yourself as it is limited  how much I can explain in an answer. But I hope these two paragraphs above can help.
My answer is still no as it does not contradict the Meissner Effect. It is more about the expulsion of magnetic fields from the interior of the  superconductor. The thing you were asking about the penetration depth is another concept in another of itself.

Do you have any better answer to it?

I have edited my answer maybe it can be of more help.

It is because the density of superconductive pairs is finite. Therefor it takes a layer of finite thickness to block the external field.

Would the downvoter be so bold as to explain this?
